# FAB with ListView not showing up

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a FAB in my app which is not showing up.

I followed a tutorial and did what he did in (XML). But on his screenshot I can see the FAB but in my case it doesn't show up when there are views in the list on screen. If there is only one view/row or no row and is some space for FAB to show up then it shows up.

I think there i something wrong with my `Layout` XML.

Can anyone please tell me where is it going wrong.

Thank you.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10sp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttondesign"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Hide Arabic" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:background="@drawable/buttondesign"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Hide Reference" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button_fab_with_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fav"
        app:elevation="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nimblechapps.awesomefont.MainActivity">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10sp"
            >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25sp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttondesign"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Hide Arabic" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25sp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttondesign"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Hide Reference" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button_fab_with_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fav"
        app:elevation="4dp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Floating Action Button is under the listview. You must try this.

```
findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_fab_with_listview).bringToFront();
```